# relative path and system paths are not working in codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

When I am trying to access files from standard usr/ it is not working. and showing errors that file is missing .

I have added path but and make it work but i think this is not the correct way.

I have a workspace with 10-12 projects which are of c and cpp both.
In one project I am using cpp with thrift libraries and protocol.
in that project only I am facing issue. with I am individually building that project it is working but when building it from the main project. it starts showing error in files.

There all almost 17 projects and 16 are generating .so files and all are going to the main project. and main is generating an executable. and that executable uses all the .so files.

but In thrift only it is showing errors. before it was showing for #include i added that file so now it is showing **undefined type Name Space** ..
I think this issue is because of relative path but I am not sure

Please Help

Comment: No no  Joachim Pileborg it is /usr only but I have written usr/ means all things inside /usr .  lib bin include local etc

Comment: `usr/` is a *relative*  path, and it's relative from the working directory of your process. If your working directory is not `/` then of course you won't be able to find any files Unless you have your *own* sub-directory `usr` somewhere else?

Comment: Correct But I am having /usr only and the things inside /usr are not accessible.

Comment: Can you show some code (preferably something self-contained) that shows the problem? And where is the path problem? Somewhere in codeblocks, or somewhere in c?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Without code it's impossible to know what you're doing or what you really mean.

Comment: Thanks Joachim.. i am updating my Question please check again,